# Scraping multiple table row siblings with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I’m trying to parse a table with the following markup.

```
<table>
  <tr class="athlete">
    <td colspan="2" class="name">Alex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="run">
    <td>5.00</td>
    <td>10.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="run">
    <td>5.20</td>
    <td>10.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="end"></tr>
  <tr class="athlete">
    <td colspan="2" class="name">John</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="run">
    <td>5.00</td>
    <td>10.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="end"></tr>
</table>
```

I need to loop through each .athlete table row and get each sibling .run table row underneath until I reach the .end row. Then repeat for the next athlete and so on. Some .athlete rows have two .run rows, others have one.

Here’s what I have so far. I loop through the athletes:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://myurl.com"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc.css(".athlete").each do |athlete|
  puts athlete.at_css("name").text
  # Loop through the sibling .run rows until I reach the .end row
  # output the value of the td’s in the .run row
end
```

I can’t figure out how to get each sibling .run row, and stop at the .end row. I feel like it would be easier if the table was better formed, but unfortunately I don’t have control of the markup. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voilà

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = <<DOC
<table>
  <tr class="athlete">
    <td colspan="2" class="name">Alex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="run">
    <td>5.00</td>
    <td>10.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="run">
    <td>5.20</td>
    <td>10.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="end"></tr>
  <tr class="athlete">
    <td colspan="2" class="name">John</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="run">
    <td>5.00</td>
    <td>10.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="end"></tr>
</table>
DOC

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(doc)
# You can exclude .end, if it is always empty? and not required
trs = doc.css('.athlete, .run, .end').to_a
# This will return [['athlete', 'run', ...,'end'], ['athlete', 'run', ...,'end'] ...]
athletes = trs.slice_before{ |elm| elm.attr('class') =='athlete' }.to_a

athletes.map! do |athlete|
    {
        name: athlete.shift.at_css('.name').text,
        runs: athlete
        .select{ |tr| tr.attr('class') == 'run' }
        .map{|run| run.text.to_f }
    }
end

puts athletes.inspect
#[{:name=>"Alex", :runs=>[5.0, 5.2]}, {:name=>"John", :runs=>[5.0]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would process the table as followed:

1. Locate the table you want to process

   ```
   table = doc.at_css("table")
   ```
2. Get all the immediate rows in the table

   ```
   rows = table.css("> tr")
   ```
3. Group the rows with boundary `.athlete` and `.end`

   ```
   grouped = [[]]
   rows.each do |row|
     if row['class'] == 'athlete' and grouped.last.empty?
       grouped.last << row
     elsif row['class'] == 'end' and not grouped.last.empty?
       grouped.last << row
       grouped << []
     elsif not grouped.last.empty?
       grouped.last << row
     end
   end
   grouped.pop if grouped.last.empty? || grouped.last.last['class'] != 'end'
   ```
4. Process the grouped rows

   ```
   grouped.each do |group|
     puts "BEGIN: >> #{group.first.text} <<"
     group[1..-2].each do |row|
       puts "  #{row.text.squeeze}"
     end
     puts "END: >> #{group.last.text} <<"
   end
   ```